# Uploading a picture to Foodspotting, Google Local and Yelp at the same time

Tags: yelp.com, google-my-business, foodspotting

Is there any way to upload a picture to Foodspotting, Google Local and Yelp at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to upload a picture to Foodspotting, Google Local and Yelp at the same time.